# Python: pyodbc, Microsoft Access: update dates in table, Too few Parameters

Tags: python, sql, ms-access

Versions in use: `python 3.7.2rc1` and `Microsoft Access 2003`

I am trying to get a specific record based on an ID and date. If I delete the date parameters it works fine. But using the `mydate` variable I get the error as shown below.

```
price_list__only = date_out[0]
#print('pricelist = '+str(price_list__only))
mydate = datetime.date(2018, 12, 1)
#print(mydate)

sql = '''
SELECT * FROM view_price_list WHERE SuppID = ? and "Price List Date" =     ?
'''
parmeters = (price_list__only, mydate)
cursor.execute(sql,parmeters)
```

> Error output: pyodbc.Error: ('07002',[07002], [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 3

Comment: MS Access does not use double quotes for identifiers. Use brackets or backticks to escape spaces and special characters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to "bracketise" field names with spaces (or better: avoid these):

```
SELECT * FROM view_price_list WHERE SuppID = ? and [Price List Date] = ?
```

or perhaps correct the typos:

```
SELECT * FROM view_price_list WHERE SuppID = ? and Price_List_Date = ?
```

Comment: @Parfait: Thanks. They were a left-over from the copy-paste. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike most relational databases following [ANSI SQL-1992](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), MS Access SQL ([generally ANSI -89 Level 1 compliant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/comparison-of-microsoft-access-sql-and-ansi-sql)) does not use double quotes for identifiers such as tables or columns. In Access (like Python), double quotes are equivalent to single quotes to enclose string literals.

Therefore, you must escape identifiers with spaces or special characters `?!@#$%^&*()_+`, or matching [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2). Either use square brackets, a feature shared with SQL Server and SQLite:

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM view_price_list 
         WHERE SuppID = ? and [Price List Date] = ?
      '''
```

Or use backticks, a feature shared with MySQL:

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM view_price_list 
         WHERE SuppID = ? and `Price List Date` = ?
      '''
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it, I had a problem elsewhere in my code that made it seem like this part was not working but all good now. Thanks again.